# MongoDB: How to check performance in replica set?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-replication, replicaset

I created 4 VMs using Virtual Box, and I configured a replica set use 3 VMs

VM1 Primary

VM2 Secondary

VM3 Secondary

and VM4 is isolated from all others.

I did this to check if I perform a heavy query on a mongo Db replica server and a normal server will I get faster results from the server with replica set or not.

To my surprise Query on VM1 and VM4 gave the result in almost same time.

I think I have some problem in my approach, Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

P.S  I also checked it with different read preferences. no difference.

Answer (score 0):

A replica set is not designed to improve performance or spread load.  It is for fault tolerance.

When reading, the query is handled by a single node whether it is a replica or not, so it is not surprising that the performance is the same.